# Why is my setOnItemClickListener not working?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, listener, onitemclicklistener

I have a custom ListView.

This is the source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_string"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginLeft="90dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/edit_btn"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/delete_btn"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/edit_btn"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the XML code of my activity where the listView is defined:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@color/AliceBlue"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".IntroductionActivity">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:fastScrollAlwaysVisible="false" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is source code of my activity, which is using the ListView:

```
package com.bundas.tobesmart;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class IntroductionActivity extends Activity {
    private ListView list;
    private Activity activity = this;
    private Context context = this;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_introduction);

        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i = 0; i < 50; ++i){
            arrayList.add("Number " + (i+1));
        }


        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(arrayList, this, this);



        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Oteviram Cheat Activity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("Inside onItem atd..", "Mel se provest Toast");
            }
        });

        Log.d("tag1", "testiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiing");
        list.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_introduction, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Why isn't the OnItemClickListener working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.. setting focus false for the list item would work

```
list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
list.setItemsCanFocus(false);
```